# Qual é o processo de geração de arquivos pdf's?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, pdf, programação-funcional

Como é o processo interno para gerar um arquivo pdf?

Indiferente da linguagem de programação que está gerando-o.

Comment: [Neste link](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) você pode ver as especificações do formato PDF da Adobe (ISO 32000).